# Jenkinsfile - replace a "when" statement with "if" for dynamic stages

Tags: jenkins, groovy, build, jenkins-groovy

Consider a repository with structure:

```
parent
  - subdir1
  - subdir2
```

Where each `subdir` is an independent project and has its own `Jenkinsfile`.  We want to call these from a parent pipeline conditionally based on if any files inside a subdirectory have changed.  This is straightforward for a single directory.

```
stage('build subdir') {
        when {
            changeset "subdir/**"
        }
        steps {
            load "subdir/Jenkinsfile"
        }
    }
```

But the project actually has say 20 subdirectories.  I have followed https://www.zippyops.com/loops-in-pipeline20210420103750 to replace this with a loop, but to no avail.

```
def final repos = ["subdir1", "subdir2", "subdir3"]

pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {

        stage('Run builds') {
            steps {
                checkout scm
                script {
                    repos.each {repo ->
                        stage(repo) {
                            when {
                                changeset "${repo}/**"
                            }
                            steps {
                                load "${repo}/Jenkinsfile"
                            }
                        }
                    }}}}}
```

It fails because the command `when` is invalid under a `step` block.  `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'when' found among steps...` - any ideas how to sidestep this?

Main use case is reducing boilerplate and being able to dynamically add directories to this monorepo without having to touch Jenkinsfile each time.

Answer (score 1):

When you are in a `Script` block. You can no longer use Declarative syntax like `when{}`. So the best option here is to preprocess the changeSet and get a clean list of directories. Here is my take on this. To further improve your Pipeline, you can probably run each stage in parallel as well.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {

        stage('Run builds') {
            steps {
                checkout scm
                script {
                    def repos = getSubDirectoriesChanged()
                    repos.each {repo ->
                        stage(repo) {
                            steps {
                                load "${repo}/Jenkinsfile"
                            }
                        }
                    }}}}}


def getSubDirectoriesChanged() {
    def filesList = []
    def changeLogSets = currentBuild.changeSets

    // First Lets get all the files that changed. 
    for (int i = 0; i < changeLogSets.size(); i++) {
        def entries = changeLogSets[i].items
        for (int j = 0; j < entries.length; j++) {
            def entry = entries[j]
            def files = new ArrayList(entry.affectedFiles)
                for (int k = 0; k < files.size(); k++) {
                def file = files[k]
                filesList.add(file.path)
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Let's filter the directories, having a / means it's a directory, there can be multiple files changed
    // in the same directory, so we need to drop the duplicates.
    return filesList.findAll{ it.contains("/") }.collect { it.split('/')[0] }.unique()
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you- I will play with this and come back and mark as accepted answer eventually hwen I get somet iem to try it.  Thx for help